# CoreData property cannot be found in forward class object

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

i am new to coredata and trying to use magicalRecord library for my project.
this problem involves 2 class : CPLink and LinkParsedData. And these 2 classes are generated by xCode from the enetities.

```
CPLink:
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class CPData, LinkParsedData;

@interface CPLink : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * state;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * uid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CPData *cpdata;
@property (nonatomic, retain) LinkParsedData *parsedData;

@end

LinkParsedData
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class CPLink;

@interface LinkParsedData : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * articleContent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * articleTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ogDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ogImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ogTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * postDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CPLink *cplink;

@end
```

and in another view. I would like to access the ogImage with this syntax.

```
self.cpLink.parsedData.ogImage
```

It shoews that property 'ogImage' cannot be found in forward class object 'LinkParsedata'

any idea?

Comment: Have you correctly `#import`ed `LinkParsedata` in the view's .m file?

Comment: Forward class error usually comes when you have not imported in .m file